# Express '\' in SQL without breaking Netbeans syntax highlighting

Tags: sql, netbeans, plsql, syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a PL/SQL function which uses the string literal `'\'`. This breaks SQL syntax highlighting in Netbeans, like so:

[image: Netbeans SQL syntax highlighting bug]

Looks like the backslash is erroneously being interpreted as an escape character. `'\\'` highlights correctly but is of course not the same string. How can I express `'\'` in a way which will not break the buggy highlighter?

Comment: `backslash := chr(92);`

Comment: @Egor Ha! I actually tried that, but misread the ASCII table and put in the octal value (`chr(134)`) instead. Silly mistake. Your way works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, clue's in the picture. Since the highlighter's interpreting the comment as part of the string, you can put `'` in a comment to "end the string" and fix the highlighting.

[image: Workaround for Netbeans SQL highlighting bug]

Comment: This is still wrong. `Netbeans syntax highlighting is dumb` is a comment but is not appearing in black.